# Prevent deleting a folder during uninstall

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, windows-installer

Is there any possible way to prevent files in a folder being removed or from over written during re installation? i have a folder where i store some templates for sending mails which user can edit.I have added the basic templates in my setup and so during re installation  it removes the templates which the user might have already edited and places a new copy of the template.How can i prevent this?Should i use `installer class` or is there any property that i can use?Please Guide.

Comment: Are thjese files in your ProgramFiles tree? Can you consider moving them to AppData\Local or ProgramData ?

Comment: @ryadavilli no :-( since its already given to users they wont like a path change now.They need the templates to be associated with the folder where software is installed.any other way?please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

this can be done by selecting the file properties and setting the value of permanent to true.

Answer (score 1):

See:

[File Versioning Rules (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Especially:

[Neither File Has a Version (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You are using a tool that makes every single file a key file of it's own components.  Therefore, you should already be getting this default behavior.  If you set Permanent, they should not get removed.   You said that the use "can" modify these files.  The behavior is that if they haven't modified the files, they will get overwritten  and if they have modified the files they will not.

However, IMO, a better pattern is to have an override directory that users can copy templates to and modify.  You can get into undesired behaviors on upgrades resulting from the conflict of 1) My new build fixes something and 2)  I can't install it because the old stuff has user data.   This is especially true for things like XML files.